# Can Macro Folders be deployed in a change set?

Tags: metadata-api, change-set, folder, macros

For a user story, I created several Macro folders. That is, I went to the standard list view of Macro, clicked "New Folder", and did this multiple times.

Now I need to deploy them to other sandboxes. But when I try to upload a change set with the folders, I get the following error:

```
Your upload failed. We're sending you an e-mail with more information.
```

When I receive the email, this is the message:

```
The following outbound change set upload failed due to a system error:

Change set: <Change Set Name> (<Change Set Id>)
Organization: <Org Name> (Developer Sandbox) (<Source Org Id>)
User: <User Name> (<User Id>)
Error Number: 320873649-80648 (885809063)

Please try to upload your change set again. If it does not succeed, contact Customer Support and provide the error number listed above.



Thank You,
salesforce.com
```

I've tried uploading the change set multiple times, and it always ends the same way. My team is also not sure how to solve it.

Is there some missing org configuration? Or am I missing something obvious? Or doing something Salesforce doesn't permit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible with change sets. There's the following [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003gI3QAI&title=unable-to-upload-macro-quick-text-folders-via-change-sets) closed as "no fix" as it's "Working as Designed"

In the Metadata API, [folder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_folder.htm) only lists 4 types - excluding macros (and quick text).

- Document folder
- Email folder (available for Salesforce Classic email templates only)
- Report folder
- Dashboard folder

The only workaround is to manually create the folders in the target org.